# Infinite scroll backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, infinite-scroll

I would like to have an infinite/endless scroll data rendering from a JSON feed. I am interested in accomplishing something similar to Pinterest or Google Reader using Backbone/Underscore/jQuery.

**How do I apply the [infiniScroll.js](https://github.com/joneath/infiniScroll.js) module to my backbone view?** The goal is to fetch and append the next page's ("page" URL parameter) tweets when you scroll near the end of the page. Problem: when reaching the bottom of page, same JSON page feed is fetched. How to change the `page` parameter in the URL to be `&page=2`, etc.

**Demo:** http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19974044/test.html OR http://jsfiddle.net/k4rPP/3/

```
// Define the model
Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend();

// Define the collection
Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tweet,
    // Url to request when fetch() is called
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&trim_user=false&count=10&screen_name=cnn&page=1&callback=?',
    parse: function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    // Overwrite the sync method to pass over the Same Origin Policy
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        var that = this;
        var params = _.extend({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: that.url,
            processData: false
        }, options);

        return $.ajax(params);
    }
});

// Define the View
TweetsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        // create a collection
        this.collection = new Tweets;
        // Fetch the collection and call render() method
        var that = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function () {
                that.render();
            }
        });
        // infiniScroll.js integration
        this.infiniScroll = new Backbone.InfiniScroll(this.collection, {success: this.appendRender, param:'page', includePage:true});
    },
    // Use an extern template
    template: _.template($('#tweetsTemplate').html()),

    render: function () {
        // Fill the html with the template and the collection
        $(this.el).html(this.template({
            tweets: this.collection.toJSON()
        }));
    }
});

var app = new TweetsView({
    // define the el where the view will render
    el: $('body')
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url attribute can be specified as a function rather than a string. So you could replace it with something like this:

```
...
currentPage: 0,
url: function() {
  this.currentPage++;
  return 'https://path.to.url/?page=' + this.currentPage;
},
...
```

Comment: you overrode the model's `sync` function, and in there it's not using url as a function. By default, sync will check and use it appropriately. You will need to change `url: that.url,` to `url: that.url(),`. I'm not sure how to hook it up to the infiniscroll plugin, as I've never used it before. I'll take a look tonight when I'm off work.

Comment: I noticed that in your infiniscroll constructor, your success callback is set to `this.appendRender`. This should be set to `this.render` as it's your render function that you want to call when it's done fetching.